# Magento 1: admin product grid column value disappear on name search

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, collection, grid, column

I'm facing an interesting problem regarding a custom modification to the backend Catalog Product grid.

NB: *I'm currently using a module adding columns to this grid via an observer*.

Nevertheless, the problem is also happening if I create a copy of `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php` under `app/code/local`.

Here are the modifications I have made, I've changed the attribute I'm using with the native `tax_class_id` attribute so anyone can replicate the issue:

Modified the `_prepareCollection` method:

Before:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
```

After:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('tax_class_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
```

Modified the `_prepareColumns` method by adding:

```
// Get the attribute corresponding to my custom attribute
$attribute = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
        ->setCodeFilter("tax_class_id")
        ->getFirstItem();

// Get the attribute options
$attrOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

// Convert the options to an array that can be used as the 'options' parameter for the addColumn method
$optionsArr = array();
foreach ($attrOptions as $option)
{
    $optionsArr[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}

$this->addColumn('tax_class_id',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Tax'),
        'width' => '60px',
        'index' => 'tax_class_id',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'filter_index' => 'tax_class_id',
        'options' => $optionsArr
));
```

**That works perfectly fine in the following cases**:

- Access Catalog > Product grid
- Filter by product type, attribute set, sku, price, quantity, visibility, status as well as the new custom column.
- Sort by product type, attribute set, sku, price, quantity, visibility, status as well as the new custom column.
- Browse via pager
- Change page size

However **as soon as I start dealing with the name column**, every cell of my custom column become empty/the product value is not displayed anymore, so when I:

- Filter by name
- Sort by name

**How is that specific name column affecting my current custom column and how can I fix the issue ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging very deep into Magento code and getting my hands dirty as I expected, I've found the root cause of the problem.

When the collection is loaded (implicitely via `getFirstItem` in @Simon test script), the `_loadAttributes` method from `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` is triggered.

The **goal of this method** is to load the attributes we've requested via the `addAttributeToSelect` method.

Here is a quick summary of the method code flow:

- ***Get the attributes type and attributes corresponding tables*** for each attributes to be selected (in our test script it would be `int` / `catalog_product_entity_id` and `decimal` / `catalog_product_entity_decimal` )
- ***Generate one SQL query per distinct attributes table*** (in our test, there is two different SQL queries : one for `price` attribute and one for the `tax_class_id` attribute)
- Finally it ***loops through the select groups previously generated and for each select group, proceed to an UNION ALL before setting the corresponding values to the entity***.

That very last part of the code is very important, as this ***is where the bug is located*** (if you did not guess until now, it is a **Magento bug**).

> Ready for some reading ?

So let's look at the code now, in our `_loadAttributes` method, we have the following code:

```
$selectGroups = Mage::getResourceHelper('eav')->getLoadAttributesSelectGroups($selects);
foreach ($selectGroups as $selects) {
    if (!empty($selects)) {
        try {
            $select = implode(' UNION ALL ', $selects);
            $values = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::printException($e, $select);
            $this->printLogQuery(true, true, $select);
            throw $e;
        }

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $this->_setItemAttributeValue($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, right before the loop, the `getLoadAttributesSelectGroups` method from `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4` looks like this:

```
public function getLoadAttributesSelectGroups($selects)
{
    $mainGroup  = array();
    foreach ($selects as $eavType => $selectGroup) {
        $mainGroup = array_merge($mainGroup, $selectGroup);
    }
    return array($mainGroup);
}
```

Did you spot the `return` statement ? We **return an array of arrays**. So the loop in our `_loadAttributes` method is **never really used as there will always be one and only item (containing arrays) in the `$selectGroups` variable.**

As this variable is not properly set, we keep going and reach the **heart of the bug which is causing `int` being converted to `decimals`**:

```
$select = implode(' UNION ALL ', $selects);
```

So our `$selects` variable contains two selects from two different tables of two different types (int and decimal).

What does the MySQL documentation has to tell us about this:

> The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the
>   column names for the results returned. **Selected columns listed in
>   corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same
>   data type**. (For example, the first column selected by the first
>   statement should have the same type as the first column selected by
>   the other statements.)
>
> **If the data types of corresponding SELECT columns do not match**, the
>   types and lengths of the columns in the UNION result take into account
>   the values retrieved by all of the SELECT statements.

So, **implicitely, MySQL converts our int values to decimal values** as it is not possible to convert the other way around.

And **that only happens if you try to select decimal and int attributes**, as if you select varchar attributes for instance, the int and decimal results will be converted to varchar and the problem disappears.

> So how do I fix that ?

First, we need to find what is buggy:

- Is it the `_loadAttributes` method ?
- Is it the `getLoadAttributesSelectGroups` method ?

Well, I have found only one other reference to the `getLoadAttributesSelectGroups` method, it is under the `_loadModelAttributes` of the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract` model and it looks like this:

```
$selectGroups = Mage::getResourceHelper('eav')->getLoadAttributesSelectGroups($selects);
foreach ($selectGroups as $selects) {
    if (!empty($selects)) {
        $select = $this->_prepareLoadSelect($selects);
        $values = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
        foreach ($values as $valueRow) {
            $this->_setAttributeValue($object, $valueRow);
        }
    }
}
```

So in Magento developers mind, that function should definitely be returning an array with several entries as everytime this function is called, a `foreach` statement is used to loop through it.

So I'll give you the fix I've applied:

In `getLoadAttributesSelectGroups` method of `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4`, replace:

```
return array($mainGroup);
```

With:

```
return $mainGroup;
```

In `_loadAttributes` method of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`, replace:

```
$select = implode(' UNION ALL ', $selects);
$values = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
```

With:

```
if (is_array($selects)) {
    $select = implode(' UNION ALL ', $selects);
} else {
    $select = $selects;
}
$values = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
```

In the `_loadModelAttribures` of the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract`, replace:

```
$select = $this->_prepareLoadSelect($selects);
$values = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

With:

```
if (is_array($selects)) {
    $select = $this->_prepareLoadSelect($selects);
} else {
    $select = $selects;
}
$values = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

> Well done you made it to the end and so did I.

Edit: **regarding the bug on Magento 2**, I've created a Pull Request that can be found here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/3705 (related issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3704)

Edit 2: **regarding the bug on Magento 1**, I've reported the bug you can find the report here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1346

Comment: nice work, are you going to make a pull request for m2? (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/ResourceModel/Helper.php#L83 - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php#L1178)

Comment: @DavidVerholen thanks, yeah I will try to make the PR by the end of the week

Comment: @DavidVerholen M2 issue has been created: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3704

Comment: This is really interesting, however the solution proposed is not always working for me, as I receive the exception:
"union() only accepts an array of Zend_Db_Select instances of sql query strings"

I solved in the following way:

1. // Initialise an empty array to contain values
2. // Perform a query for each select, without union
3. // Merge the values of all the selects into an array
4. // Now call the attributeValues by passing the array, and not the select results. You can see the final file in this public Gist: https://gist.github.com/eperrotta/60c6ea2a9824f05d7634d36c1c9cb163

Comment: @EnzoPerrotta I can't replicate your problem, could you post a simple test script (as the second answer below) that I can use to replicate your issue when my fix is applied ?

Answer (score 3):

I digged into that a bit and found out that this is a really weird Magento behaviour. I did not find a solution yet, but wanted to share my findings anyway.

The issue is actually that if you have a product collection and:

- have the flat catalog disabled (which is always the case in the backend)
- filter/sort by `name`
- select the `tax_class_id` and the `price` attribute

then the `tax_class_id` will not return integer values (e.g. `1`), but floating values (e.g. `1.0000`). That is why the options renderer (`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Options`) does not detect the correct value and therefore does not show anything.

You can reproduce this weird behaviour with this little test script:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('tax_class_id')
    ->addAttributeToSort('name');

// toggle this to see the weird result
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');

// to make the script faster and lighter
$collection->setPageSize(1);

if ($collection->getSize() > 0) {
    var_dump($collection->getFirstItem()->getData('tax_class_id'));
}

// does not help, the SQL is exactly the same
// echo (string) $collection->getSelect();
```

Comment: Very helpful, on a side note, it's important to disable flat catalog when using your script directly in the browser `/test.php`. I'm investigating the problem right now, gotta feeling I'm about to get really deep into Magento core and get my hands dirty ^^